# Scheduling Visual Studio Team Services load test

Tags: mstest, azure-devops, schedule

Is it possible to schedule Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online) load test, so that it will run automatically in a specified time? 
I am able to run the load test in Team Services using the VS IDE and I am able to see the result but I need to configure the test in such a way that it will get triggered every night and I need to see the out put in VS IDE.

I came to know that mstest command can be used to run the load test from command line, I thought to create a batch script that run the load test and make task scheduler to run the load test but form this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/03/14/visual-studio-online-load-test-troubleshooting-guide/.

I understood that Team Services does not support mstest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a build definition in your VSTS team project and add "Cloud-based Load Test" task in the build definition to trigger the VSTS Load Test. And then set this build definition to run by schedule. Refer to this link for details: [Scheduling Load Test Execution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/11/23/scheduling-load-test-execution/).

Comment: Do I need to use TFS for this

Comment: @Aathira No, you just need to use your VSO account.

Comment: @ Eddie Thanks for the help :) 
Following link helped me to create the script to run the load test using command line.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/08/24/cloud-load-test-support-in-mstest-exe-command-line-and-xaml-builds/

Comment: I am able to run one load test using the script below:
mstest /TestContainer:"C:\Normal.loadtest" /testsettings:"Local.testsettings" /resultsfile:"c:\MyResults.trx",
but if I try to run multiple load tests like this :
mstest /TestContainer:"C:\Normal.loadtest" /TestContainer:"C:\Peak.loadtest" /testsettings:"Local.testsettings" /resultsfile:"c:\MyResults.trx"
only the first load test gets queued in VSO (Normal.loadtest) and no result of second load test (Peak.loadtest) while the command prompt is showing the following result:
Test Run Completed.
  Completed  2